# Best estimation of a fitting parameter to measured data

Tags: regression, estimation, python, fitting

My goal is to estimate a parameter $\alpha_1 = (\alpha_{11}, \alpha_{12})$ which provides the best fit of certain measured data (a readout of some currents in a set of positions for a set of loads) to a hypothesized model.

After some hypothesis on the underlying data, the model to be fitted is represented by:
$$
I_{Ndc_{(1,k)}l} = \frac{I_{dc_{(k)}} - \alpha_{(1,k)} i_{ac_{(k)}}} {I_{dc_{(1)}} + I_{dc_{(2)}} - \alpha_{(1,1)} i_{ac_{(1)}} - \alpha_{(1,2)} i_{ac_{(2)}}  }
$$
where $k=1,2$. Therefore there are two functions, $I_{Ndc_{(1,1)}l}$ and $I_{Ndc_{(1,2)}l}$.

The measured data are the $I_{dc_{(k)}}$ and $i_{ac_{(k)}}$ and are represented by a $n\times m$ matrix, where each column is a different position and each row is a different load.

The idea is that there is a certain $\alpha_1 = (\alpha_{11}, \alpha_{12})$ which can make both $I_{Ndc_{(1,k)}l}$ independent of load variations (or independent to a variation of the 0 axis) for each position (or 1 axis).

Since I don't know how to formalize it and find the best estimator, I tried by intuition by finding (with python) the $\alpha_1 = (\alpha_{11}, \alpha_{12})$ which minimizes the unbiased variance (`ddof=1`) of $I_{Ndc_{(1,k)}l}$ in each position (means computing the variance on axis 0)

```
def res(alpha):
    alpha_11, alpha_12 = alpha
    INdc11l_meas = ((Idc1_meas - alpha_11 * iac1_meas)/
                    (Idc1_meas + Idc2_meas - alpha_11 * iac1_meas - alpha_12 * iac2_meas))

    INdc12l_meas = ((Idc2_meas - alpha_12 * iac2_meas)/
                    (Idc1_meas + Idc2_meas - alpha_11 * iac1_meas - alpha_12 * iac2_meas))

    var_INdc11l = sc.var(INdc11l_meas, axis=0, ddof=1) #Unbiased estimator ddof=1
    var_INdc12l = sc.var(INdc12l_meas, axis=0, ddof=1)

    return var_INdc11l + var_INdc12l

alpha_opt = optimize.minimize(res, [0,0])['x']
```

$I_{Ndc_{(1,k)}l}$ with `alpha_opt` results in superimposed lines (each line a different load):
[image: Lines with alpha]

What I am asking at this point is:

- Can this method be formalized in some way or have a particular meaning?
- Is there a better way to estimate $\alpha_1$?
- Is it possible to prove that it is the best estimator?
- What is the difference with minimizing the pairwise distance squared since it provides the same result? (changing the return statement with: `return sc.sum(distance.pdist(INdc11l_meas, 'sqeuclidean'))`)

As a second step, with the $\alpha_1$ already known, it was needed to find a relation that can be inverted to find the position by measuring the currents $I_{dc_{(k)}}$ and $i_{ac_{(k)}}$. At this step they are not any more a matrix $n \times m$, but a scalar value, which provides a scalar $I_{Ndc_{(1,k)}l}$.

Again, by intuition, I supposed that by minimizing the variance, it is equivalent to minimize the distance of each point to the expectation and therefore the expectation to be a good candidate for that function

```
E = sc.mean(INdc11l_meas, axis=0)
f = sc.interpolate.interp1d(position_meas.T[:,0], E.T, 'cubic')
f_inv11 = lambda I: sc.optimize.root(lambda p,I: f(p) - I, [10], (I))

# From here Idc1_meas, Idc2_meas, iac1_meas, iac2_meas are scalars and instantaneous measurements
def find_pos11(Idc1_meas, Idc2_meas, iac1_meas, iac2_meas, alpha_1 = alpha_opt, f_inv11 = f_inv11):
    return f_inv11(((Idc1_meas - alpha_11 * iac1_meas)/(Idc1_meas + Idc2_meas - alpha_1[0]* iac1_meas - alpha_1[1] * iac2_meas)))
```

The expectation is in yellow and the interpolated function in black:
[image: interpolated]

What I am asking at this point is:

- Does it make sense?
- Is there a better way to estimate `find_pos11`?
- Is it possible to prove that it is the best available or to find which is the best?

Sorry in advance for my lack of rigour.

Comment: I can provide a Python non-linear surface fitting example with both surface and contour plots if it might be of some use.

Comment: Yes please. Which is the advantage over the method in the question?

Comment: <<by intuition, I supposed that by minimizing the variance, it is equivalent to minimize the distance of each point to the expectation >>

But how do you know where the expectation is?

Comment: @user8948 The lines, for a certain $\alpha_1$, can be obtained using measured data and the expectation should be a line somewhere inside those lines, which ideally would be superimposed by hypotheses and therefore coincide with the expectation.

Comment: Well, yes. But you have to compute those expectations, right?

Comment: @user8948 Well, in my solution yes, since I supposed the expectation to be the estimator for `f`

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting the whole story. The usual naive approach to curve fitting (often good enough) is to find the parameters that minimize the deviation  (maybe absolute, maybe squared) of the resulting curve to the data. This gives you a curve with the expectations.

Comment: @user8948 There are multiple resulting curves and the variance that I minimize, on a 2d plane, is on each vertical slice, maybe I should add a plot.

Comment: Also: are your results good? That's important information. (I) "Will my results be good with this" and (II) "My results appear to be good, is this solid" are different questions. You can stress test your (appears-to-be-working) algorithm with cross-validation, the jackknife/bootstrap, etc. even if you can't math it out yet.

Comment: @user8948 I added some pictures. Yes:  "My results appear to be good, is this solid?"

Comment: You asked, "Which is the advantage over the method in the question?" - that you can work with 3D surfaces, I understood this might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, here is an example Python surface fitter using
non-linear curve fitting with 3D scatter plot, 3D surface plot,
and contour plot. This example uses manually supplied initial
parameter estimates, but the scipy differential_evolution module
has a genetic algorithm to help determine these initial
estimates and I can give an example of that also.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, alpha, beta):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    return a * (x**alpha) * (y**beta)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    # these are the same as scipy default values in this example
    # if you do not have initial parameter estimates, they can
    # be estimated using scipy's differential_evolution genetic
    # algorithm module, I can supply an example if needed
    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that minimizing the ensemble variance (as an objective function) is equivalent to minimizing the pair-wise distances between the variables

$$\text{FullSimplify}\left(\sum _{i=1}^N \left(y_i-\frac{\sum _{j=1}^N y_j}{N}\right)^2-\frac{\sum _{i=1}^N \sum _{j=i}^N \left(y_i-y_j\right){}^2}{N}\text{/.}\, \{N\to 20\}\right)=0$$

Comment: Nice! I wonder how to extend to any N...